# C# UWP's WebView2 is null on JS side after repetitive reopening

Tags: c#, uwp, webview2

I have a problem with WebView2 in UWP application. After some repetitive opening and closing of the webview at some random point I noticed that `WebMessageReceived` is not being invoked. After some further investigation I found that in JS side `window.chrome.webview` is null but the WebView content is loaded and works fine except the message received event. The case appears randomly. It might be on the second or 15th reopening or might not appear at all.

I asume the problem is in creation and deletion of the WebView. I've looked through initialization and disposig of WebView. I tried to do it in proper order. I have a UserControl in which I have the WebView. Below is the order of the lifetime of the events.

1. UserControl's constructor is being called.
2. UserControl's `UserControl.Loaded` is being called. It sets `WebView2.Source`  and It calls `ConfigureWebView` function
3. Configuration function does following

```
 private async Task ConfigureWebView()
        {
            WebView2.CoreWebView2Initialized += WebView2_CoreWebView2Initialized;

            await WebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
            WebView2.CoreWebView2.OpenDevToolsWindow();
        }
```

4. Now I am waiting for `WebView2.CoreWebView2Initialized`
5. In the initialized I subscribe to `WebView2.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded`

```
 private void WebView2_CoreWebView2Initialized(WebView2 sender, CoreWebView2InitializedEventArgs args)
        {
            WebView2.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded += CoreWebView2_DOMContentLoaded;
        }
```

6. In the `CoreWebView2_DOMContentLoaded` I subscribe to `WebMessageReceived`

```
private void CoreWebView2_DOMContentLoaded(CoreWebView2 sender, CoreWebView2DOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
        {
            WebView2.WebMessageReceived += WebView2_WebMessageReceived;


        }
```

7. And for closing in UserControls `Unloaded` event I am calling this

```
   private void DisposeWebView()
        {
            WebView2.Source = null;
            WebView2.WebMessageReceived -= WebView2_WebMessageReceived;
            WebView2.CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded -= CoreWebView2_DOMContentLoaded;
            WebView2.CoreWebView2Initialized -= WebView2_CoreWebView2Initialized;
            WebView2.Close();
            WebView2 = null;
        }
```

Comment: When you set WebView2.Source the WebView2 will begin initialization and navigation of its CoreWebView2. You should add the CoreWebView2Initialized event handler before setting Source to avoid a potential race. During the CoreWebView2Initialized event you should add your WebMessageReceived event handler to avoid a potential race with the JS in the WebView2 posting its event before you have your native code's event handler. Can you add to your question what your script is like, when it runs, and when it posts message to native?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response. For script I use "EcecuteScriptAsync" method, and in JS I am calling postMessage after the script is recieved. After debuging a bit it seems like the problem is in webview, because the js file is a bit big. When I am hitting a breakpoint on Initialized handler or writing Thread.Sleep or Reloading the webview it begun to work. So I asume WebView initialization is done asynchronously and it is not managing to create in js side but somehow it thinks that the content is loaded. Still don't know how to fix the issue.